# Can't assign to function call

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why does this error occur:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

With this code:

```
import random 
weapon=['sword','spear','miss']
myhealth=4
cpuhealth=4
sword=.5
spear=.25
miss=0

cpuweapon=random.choice(weapon)
myweapon=random.choice(weapon)
print(myweapon) 
print("vs.") 
print(cpuweapon)

int(a)=(myhealth/cpuweapon)
int(b)=(cpuhealth/myweapon)
if a>b:
    print("YOU WIN")
if a>b:
    print("YOU WIN")
```

Comment: Just what exactly is `int(a)=(myhealth/cpuweapon)` supposed to be doing? And please explain your understanding of it so that we can find out where your mental model went a little awry.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by @AndyG, your `cpuweapon` is a string, you need to get the damage associated with that weapon, so make a dictionary

```
weapon = {'sword':0.5, 'spear': 0.25, 'miss': 0.0}
```

Then you can select the weapon by

```
cpuweapon=random.choice(list(weapon.keys()))
```

Then you can get the damage associated with that weapon from the dictionary

```
a = int(myhealth/weapon[cpuweapon])
```

Although I'm not sure why you aren't subtracting the damage from your health, but I left it as division since that's what you seem to be doing. Another reason you may want to subtract is that the value for `miss` is 0, so you will be dividing by zero, which certainly isn't what you're after.

You may be after something like

```
if myhealth - weapon[cpuweapon] <= 0:
    print("I died")

if cpuhealth - weapon[myweapon] <= 0:
    print("I killed you")
```

Comment: Except that `cpuweapon` will be a string so integer division on it is moot.

Answer (score -2):

The problem is with these lines:

```
int(a)=(myhealth/cpuweapon)
```

What you mean is:

```
a=int(myhealth/cpuweapon)
```

You can also do this with integer division (as AndyG pointed out):

```
a=myhealth//cpuweapon
```

The reason is that you must always have a name, such as `a`, `foo.bar`, etc. on the left-hand side of an assignment. Names take values, function calls produce values.

Also, as l4mpi points out, `cpuweapon` is a string, so it would be better to use a dictionary, making your final program:

```
import random
weapons = {'sword': .5, 'spear': .25, 'miss': 0}
myhealth = 4
cpuhealth = 4

cpuweapon = random.choice(list(weapons.keys()))
myweapon = random.choice(list(weapons.keys()))
print(myweapon) 
print("vs.") 
print(cpuweapon)

a = int(myhealth / weapons[cpuweapon])
b = int(cpuhealth / weapons[myweapon])

if a > b:
    print("YOU WIN")
elif a < b:
    print("YOU LOSE")
else:
    print("YOU DRAW")
```

Note that this still suffers from `ZeroDivisionError`s, as miss is `0`.

Comment: There are many more prolems with the code. Starting with the fact you can't divide an int by a string...

Comment: @l4mpi I've added that (and tested)